# Add Makrer not working android

Tags: android, maps

> ```
> public class MapActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity{
> ```

```
// Google Map
private GoogleMap googleMap;
String longitude="0";
String latitude="0";
String title="";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map); 
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }}
        catch(Exception eos)
        {

        }


}

/**
 * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
 * */
private void initilizeMap() {
    try
    {
          if (googleMap == null) {
        String longitude="27.175015";
        String latitude="78.042155";
        double savedLat = Double.parseDouble(longitude);
        double savedLng =Double.parseDouble(latitude);
        LatLng cameraLatLng = new LatLng(savedLat, savedLng);
        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng( Float.parseFloat(latitude), Float.parseFloat(longitude))).title("Marker")
        .title("mazen"));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(cameraLatLng, 17));
        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {

        }
          }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initilizeMap();
}
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.dux_sld_lft_in,
                R.anim.dux_sld_lft_out);
        return true;
    }else {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
     overridePendingTransition(R.anim.dux_sld_lft_in, R.anim.dux_sld_lft_out);
}
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

am adding markers here, but no markers are showing why? also how can i add multiple markers  to multiple places? it very funny error...because i really did exacty as tutorial i read..
hope someone can feed me with nessary help needed to finish this task

Answer (score 0):

use `addMarker()`

like :

```
myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(yourLatLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.yourmarkericon)));
```

where **myMap** is the Object of `GoogleMap` and **yourLatlng** is `Latlng` Where you want to add marker and **yourmarkericon** is icon which you want to display on map

**References**

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker

**Simple Tutorial**

http://bon-app-etit.blogspot.be/2012/12/add-informationobject-to-marker-in.html

Comment: you are mentioning above that no marker is showing.

Comment: yes, the map opens.the correct place is shown, but no marker is place. i tried different country it worked fine. but for india it did not, on taj mahal.

Comment: your latitude and longitude is wrong or may be hardcoded